# Apache Spark Counts of Events into Timestamp Buckets

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have loaded my data into a Spark dataframe and am using Spark SQL to further process it.

My Question is simple:

I have data like:

```
Event_ID Time_Stamp
1        2018-04-11T20:20..
2        2018-04-11T20:20..+1
```

and so on.

I want to get the number of events that happened every 2 minutes.

So,

My output will be:

```
Timestamp           No_of_events
2018-04-11T20:20..    2
2018-04-11T20:20..+2  3
```

In Pandas it was quite easy but I don't know how to do it in Spark SQL.

The above format data must have timestamp as a column and the number of events that happened within that time bucket (i.e. b/w timestamp and timestamp + 2 minutes) as another column.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to use a window function:

```
  df.groupBy(window(df["Time_Stamp"], "2 minutes"))
    .count()
    .show()
```

Comment: thanks, I get NameError: name 'window' is not defined

Comment: probably you are not importing org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

Comment: For pyspark, from pyspark.sql.functions import *

Comment: @CarlosVilchez Can you aggregate like `df.groupby('TimeStamp').sum()`?

Comment: @pissall, when you directly group by a timestamp, you are grouping it to the millisecond. So probably you will have as many groups as rows.

Comment: Understood @CarlosVilchez

Comment: @CarlosVilchez thanks, I edited the answer as col is not understood by Spark? Also, my timestamp column has the data type: string (nullable = true) . Can I convert it into timestamp format i.e. does Spark have a timestamp type?

Comment: I think that instead of col("Time_Stamp") you can use df["Time_Stamp"]. And about the column being a string, you can use the function `to_date` with a format